# phpMyAdmin disable Appearance Settings

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I was looking everywhere and could not find answer for that... is it possible to disable "Appearance Settings" and "Settings" at all in phpMyAdmin by config file? Or do I have to manually edit whole code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Appearance Settings": this is not configurable. "Settings": this is a menu tab, therefore it's configurable via user groups, see http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html?highlight=groups#cfg_Servers_usergroups

Comment: Thank you I just remove bunch on code from it. But this is the answer.